# Elasticsearch prints PUT statements on the console in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logging

I have written the following code in Python to use ElasticSearch for performing search on the data:

```
def main():
    start = (time.time())
    es = Elasticsearch()

    es.indices.create(index='bhar',body = {
                                 "settings":{
                                     "analysis":{
                                         "analyzer":{
                                             "my_stop_analyzer":{
                                                 "type":"custom",
                                                 "tokenizer":"standard",
                                                 "filter":["english_possessive_stemmer","lowercase","english_stop","english_stemmer"]
                                                 }
                                             },
                                          "filter":{
                                             "english_stop":{
                                             "type":"stop",
                                             "stopwords":"_english_"
                                             },
                                             "english_stemmer":{
                                             "type":"stemmer",
                                             "name":"english"
                                             },
                                             "english_possessive_stemmer": {
                                             "type":       "stemmer",
                                             "language":   "possessive_english"
                                             }
                                             }
                                             }
                                             },
                                 "mappings":{
                                     "my_type":{
                                         "properties":{
                                             "test": {
                                             "type":"text",
                                             "analyzer" : "my_stop_analyzer"
                                                 }
                                                 }
                                                 }
                                                 }
                                                 })


data = {"rid":"1","test": "This data BHX1 Pick Tower extension"}
res = es.index(index='bhar',doc_type='news',id=1,body=data,refresh=True)

query='pick tower'


match = es.search(index="bhar",body = {
                "query": {
                    "match":{
                        "test":{
                            "query":query.replace('|',' '),
                            "operator" :"AND"
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            )
if match['hits']['total']:
        print(match['hits']['hits'][0]['_source'])



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I execute this code I get the following output:

`PUT http://localhost:9200/bhar [status:400 request:0.027s]`

`{'rid': '1', 'test': 'This data BHX1 Pick Tower extension'}`

How do I control the PUT statement on the screen? Maybe send it to a log file or just not print it on the screen. Any thoughts? Thank you for reading.

Comment: You can [configure the logging](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#logging) to prevent this

Comment: But how do I first remove the print on the screen? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: That's a logging configuration that you need to adjust.

Comment: @Val Can you point me on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line before executing the elastic search query, then the POST response wont be logged into the log files,

```
logging.getLogger('elasticsearch').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you see being printed on screen is due to the following `logger.info()` call in [`connection/base.py`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/connection/base.py#L80-L83):

```
 def log_request_success(self, method, full_url, path, body, status_code, response, duration):
    ...
    logger.info(
        '%s %s [status:%s request:%.3fs]', method, full_url,
        status_code, duration
    )
```

If you don't want it to be printed out you simply need to run your code with the switch `--logging-level=WARN`

Comment: `connection/base.py`? Where will I find this script?

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer

Comment: Yeah. I mean sorry I am not able to get it. I am trying. I have not yet used logging anywhere in my code. Hence I am confused

Comment: It is not in your code, but in the code of the `elasticsearch-py` library you're using. The switch on the command line simply indicates to the logging library used by the `elasticsearch-py` library to not print out anything below WARN level, which includes the `PUT` statement you're seeing.

Comment: Yeah. I found the script. Got it. I'll try modifying it now. I don't see any LEVEL option yet

Comment: Okay I ran the code testscript.py --logging-level=WARN and still got the same output with PUT statement on the console

Comment: I didn't work. PUT statement is still on the screen. @Val